# How to recover objects after JSON.parse with parse/backbone

Tags: json, backbone.js, parse-platform

Parse.com javascript API uses a Backbone compatible object type... Or maybe Backbone it self.

I would like to know:
- How to convert a simple object into a Parse/Backbone object?
- How to convert a Parse/Backbone object into a simple object?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "simple object" to the Backbone.Model constructor, in return you will receive a Backbone model:

```
var simpleObject = {
    title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
    author: "Scheherazade"
};
new Book(simpleObject);
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor